# Is there any short cut method to find the characteristic and minimal polynomial of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given $A= \begin{bmatrix} 0 &1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\\1&0&0&0 \ \end{bmatrix}$

Is  there  any short cut method  to find the  characteristic and minimal polynomial  of $A$ ?

Comment: It helps to note that $A$ is a [Permutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix).

Comment: thanks @Omnomnomnom  but in ur link   characteristics and minmial polynomial is  not mention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps to note that $A$ is a [permutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix). In particular, we can conclude that there must be an integer $n$ such that $A^n = I$.  In this case, we find that $A^4 = I$.  Thus, the minimal polynomial of $A$ must divide $x^4 - 1$.  In fact, we find in this case that the minimal polynomial of $A$ **is** $x^4 - 1$, since $I,A,A^2,A^3$ are linearly independent.

Thus, the characteristic and minimal polynomials of $A$ are $x^4 - 1$.

More generally, we can deduce that the minimal and characteristic polynomials of a permutation matrix by using the [cycle-decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Cycle_notation) of the permutation.

Another approach is to recognize $A$ (or $A^T$ depending on your definition) as the [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix#Linear_recursive_sequences) to the polynomial $x^4 - 1$.

Yet another approach is to recognize $A$ as a [circulant matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix#Eigenvectors_and_eigenvalues).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is. You can use the [cofactor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra)) procedure. Note that if you choose eliminate the first row and the first column and then proceed eliminating the second, third and fourth row, you will have to deal with determinants of either upper triangular or diagonal matrices.

Comment: How does computing cofactors help you determine the characteristic and minimal polynomials?

Comment: The characteristic polynomial is obtained by solving $\det (A-\lambda I) = 0$, so you calculate the determinant using cofactors.

Comment: That makes sense thanks for elaborating

Comment: No problem!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Any matrix is similar to its transpose, and the transpose is seen to be the [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) of $x^4-1$.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the [minor expansion formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant) to find the characteristic polynomial:
\begin{aligned}\det(A-\lambda I)
&= \begin{vmatrix}-\lambda&1\\&-\lambda&1\\&&-\lambda&1\\1&&&-\lambda\end{vmatrix} \\
&= -\lambda\cdot\begin{vmatrix}-\lambda&1\\&-\lambda&1\\&&-\lambda\end{vmatrix} - 1\cdot\begin{vmatrix}1\\-\lambda&1\\&-\lambda&1\end{vmatrix} \\
&= -\lambda\cdot (-\lambda)^3 - 1 \cdot 1^3 \\
&= \lambda^4-1
\end{aligned}
The roots are the 4th roots of unity: $\{\pm 1,\pm i\}$. 
Since they are distinct, the minimal polynomial is the same.